# Regex alphanumeric string discarding last 3 digits and eventual initial 0s

Tags: regex, matlab

I have:

```
s = '00755C100002';
```

trying to get

```
m = '755C100';
```

I am able to discard the last 3 digits and ONE initial 0, but not all of the initial 0s:

```
regexp(s,'(?!^0*)\w*(?=\d{3}$)','match','once')
ans =
    '0755C100'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit simpler than [@Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384813/1292374) You can look for the first non-zero character and continue from there greedily

```
regexp(s,'[^0]\w*(?=\d{3}$)','match','once')
```

- `[^0]` finds first non-zero character
- `(?=\d{3}$)` skips the last three digits
- `\w*` captures everything in between

Comment: Great and intuitive. I was thinking about skipping the streak of zeros, but it's better to think about matching the first non-zero and keep going!

Comment: Note that greedy searches are in general a lot slower. For a string this size that does not matter, however, if you need to check a large string, non greedy might be better.

Comment: @Nick non-greedy searches are not **in sgenaral** slower. It depends on the situation. It is an old misconception. You can read more about it [in this article](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance). And as far as I know when they are slower they are not **a lot** slower. They are marginally slower.

Answer (score 2):

Always fun with `regexp` try using:

```
regexp(s, '[^0]+?(\w*?)(?=\d{3}$)', 'match', 'once')
```

`(?=\d{3}$)` --> look forward `(?=` `)` for 3 digits `\d{3}` at the end `$`

`[^0]+?` --> find non greedy `?` one or more `1` non zeros `[^0]`

`(\w*?)` --> match `(` `)` non greedy `?` zero or more `*` word-characters `\w`

Comment: it would be nice if you could provide a short explaination of your regexp pattern

Comment: I kind of like `regexp` - it's a very powerful tool, but I don't get to use it too often. I find that "expaining" regexp patterns is extremely helpful learning tool for me.

Comment: Your pattern matches '00755C100'.

Comment: @OlegKomarov Yep, I've changed it